# preg_match is not working the way it should

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a small web application called expenses whereby can save your expenses to a mysql db via php array.

Here is how it works.

In the first page, you'll have to enter the number of items that you want to save their expenses to the mysql db.

So, let's assume that you enter 3 as the number of items, you'll be redirected to another page whereby you'll be provided with textboxes where you'll enter the name of the items and their corresponding amounts and then click on save button to save it to the database.

So, how can i restrict the amount textboxes to accept only numeric characters and a dot in such a way that numeric character must start, then followed by a dot (which is optional) and it must also end with a numeric character.

e.g 100.8 , 250.4 , 250, 300.8 , 200.

This is my code

```
        foreach ($amount as $digit)
    {
        if((!ctype_digit($digit)) || ($digit<1) || (!preg_match("/[\.]$/",$digit)))
    {
        echo " Only positive, numeric, non-zero digits and a dot are allowed for amount of item";   
        exit();
    }
            }
```

I'll be glad if you help me correct this because it's been up to 2 days now that I've been battling with this.

Answer (score 0):

A right pattern for your task is:

```
"^[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)?$"
```

which means any non-zero digit followed by any amount of digits, and optionally followed by a dot followed by at least one digit.

That is, supposing $amount contains "123.45", your code should be:

```
if (!preg_match("^[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)?$", $amount)
{
    echo " Only positive numbers are allowed for amount of item";   
    exit();
}
```

Also, you should double all backslashes in quoted strings:

```
"/[\\.]$/"
```

because your construction

```
"/[\.]$/"
```

means that the program receives the string

```
/[.]$/
```

Comment: Thanks so much.... It worked..
Can u please explain the function of d* and d+ that you used?

Comment: `\d` (written as `"\\d"` inside quotes) stands for any digit, that is, is a shortcut for `[0-9]`. I did not use it in the first part because I don't want to allow 0, so I used `[1-9]`. `+` sign meant one or more of the previous, `*` means zero or more of the previous, `?` means zero or one of the previous, thus allowing only one dot in my pattern,

Comment: BTW, I see you are a first-time user. Did you know that you should accept an answer that you consider correct? For this you should press the green bird icon below the digit between two triangles to the left of the answer that you want to accept. In addition you can click the up triangle ("upvote") if you found the answer useful, or the down triangle ("downvote") if you found the answer counterproductive.